# how to pass a bundle to a Fragment when it is chosen from ActionTab or via ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

i have a Activity "MainActivity" and from it i start anotherActivity "messagingactivity" and pass a bundle to it. the "messaging activity" haqs two fragments "sub" and "pub" and they (sub, pub) are contained in ActionTab and it has also a viewpager to switch between the two actionTabs.

Now i want to pass the bundle from the "messagingActivity" to "sub" and "pub" fragments when the user either select one of the fragments by clicking the ActionTab or the user switch by viewpager.

how can I do this?

**Update_1**:

the resul frm the updated code is: at run time, when the mainactivity passes the bundle to the messagingactivity, by default, the fragment "sub" is shown first and at this point every this is working but when i tab on the actionbar or swipe the view pager to switch to the frgamnet "pub" the app crashes and logcat highlight either `See:onPageSelected or onTabSelected`

**UPDATED_Code_"See:onPageSelected And onTabSelected**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messagin_activity_layout);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());
    mFragList.add(new Pub_Frag());

    mPagerAdapter = new MyTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragList);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Subscribe").setTabListener(this));
    mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Publish").setTabListener(this));

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            mFragList.get(arg0).setArguments(bundle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mFragList.get(tab.getPosition()).setArguments(bundle);
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: the bundle you want to pass is static or it is dynamic?

Comment: if static then you can pass it when you added them in mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());

Comment: sorry i could not et it, what will be the diferencei it is static or dynamic, i passed the bundle from the main activiy to the messagingactivity using startactivity(intent, bundle)

Comment: okay the bundle you want to pass is fixed every time or it changes logically?

Comment: the mainactivity has some edittexts and those eittexts contents are saved to a bundle, so every tie you run the mainactivity you ccan enter different values, then i pass them to the messaging activity as mentioned in the previouse comments. hope it is clrear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of adding fragments like `mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());** Add fragment by following .

```
Sub_Frag frag = new Sub_Frag();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put("key","value");

frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then add it in your array list `mFragList.add(frag);`

Comment: thanks, now it is workin but i have two questions please.1- why the way i pssed bundle to the fragments as posted in the updated code cause the app to crash?2-in onActivitycreated() i am checking i the bundle received is null or not usinf bundle b = getArguments; and display the result in  a edittext which was initialized inside onCreateView(), but when i run the app crash and logcat say NPE at the line where Edittext.settext() exist?